# Android Java: integrating Leadbolt, landscape does work, portrait with keyboard does not

Tags: java, android, leadbolt

I am currently trying to integrate a Leadbolt banner in mine android app. Although the code worked perfectly fine in 3 previous apps, for some reason it decides gives a lot of troubles with my new app. The only difference between my previous and current app is that the first three ones were in Landscape and the keyboard was hidden.

My code (as from the Leadbolt guide):

```
public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    wv = new WebView(this);
    wv2 = new WebView(this);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    View gameView = initializeForView(new GameMain(this), false);
    layout.addView(gameView);

     final Activity act = this;

     layout.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {

     myController = new AdController(act,"351973566");
     myController.loadAd();
        }
     });

    setContentView(layout);
}
```

In Logcat most of the time i first get the message of Leadbolt Swapping plugins with the corresponding url and afterwards it gives this message.

Logcat:

> 01-12 11:51:28.525: D/szipinf(1512): Initializing inflate state

Afterwards the app does not respond to any key pressed/bypasses the input methods of my implemented library (LibGDX).

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Hi. I'm facing a similar problem. Have you managed to sort the issue out? It drives me nuts not being able to make it work. My app also freezez !

Answer (score 0):

I have used your number in my app and the ads are loading fine. I had a few issues integrating with leadbolt a while ago, but I sent my code to the support team and they fixed the problems and sent it back. Maybe you should email them directly?